# Cartoon sound "shaking about to burst" sound

Tags: sound-design

This situation is recurrent in a series of small cartoons for which I'm editing sound right now. It shows something shaking (a refrigerator in this case) just before it bursts: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwYSx3EP2t4&feature=youtu.be. I've tried several hings but the result was not satisfying:

- A rumble - the low end informaiton is not the most important thing in this case and it lacks definition. I`ll put something in but it`ll be only one layer of sound among others more important ones
- Music percussion sounds - too regular. And I`m not trying to be musical in that explicit way. This cartoons should sound  more like Treg Brown\Warner Brothers stuff than classic Disney...
- Machine guns varispeeded - too regular also... The sound should rythmic and defined but not like a metronome

Any suggestions? It`s my first animation job. Having lots of fun doing it but it's not an easy task as it may seem

Maybe this video is not the best example. A metal rattle would maybe do most of the job. But there are other examples without this metal element. And I think that maybe a metal rattle should be accompanied by other sounds in this one as well, I just don't know which exactly. Here`s another "about to burst" example, a non-metal one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWkvZHQb-4s&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 4):

analogsynth oscillator > subwoofer and lie props on subwoofer, 
perform pitch bends on oscillator and re-record prop resonating

Some audio examples of this technique from a film I did in 2011

http://www.musicofsound.co.nz/blog/sub-rattlers

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Tim! Unfortunately I don't have a sub. Michal suggested Mikke Nielsen's library where he uses such technique. I think I'm getting his library then (there were som nice samples on his website). Although, yesterday I've already got some good results combining different rattling sounds I already had in here...

Answer (score 0):

I'd try the 'rattling sound' for the fridge and that cookies box. 
for the fridge it should be something metallic with some sounds of bottles and plastic boxes shaken. Try to include some kind of crescendo into the sound. This could be done by volume or by some pitch-bended sound goong up.

Same goes for the cookies box: try some shaking-sounds of a cookies-box. For that 'explosion' you could use some volcano-eroption sounds layered with some grabbling in cookies.

Comment: Thank you for the input, Michael. Tried something like this and I think it worked quite fine! Great tip regarding the crescendo.

Answer (score 0):

Try Mikkel Nielsens *Shake, Rattle and Rumble* library or techniques he used for creating those sounds.

http://www.sonicsalute.com/portfolio/shake-rattle-and-rumble/

Best,

Comment: Thank you, Michal. I've heard Nielsen's library samples. Getting it today

Answer (score 0):

I think a earthquake rumble (better if from in a house w rattle embedded),
Train approaching(just as it passes),

Superman can:

Metal impact,
Pressure valve release

Cool animation, have fun!

Comment: Train approaching! This could work also! Thanks! Soon, I'll try to post some of the results. Now I have also Nilesenl's library, bought it yesterday